# Make a span act like an input field when overflowing

Tags: html, css

I am duplicating my input field value in a span which is placed directly on top of the input field. (Doing this to manipulate only part of the text)

I am having problems with the overflow.

Currently if I continue typing past the limit of the input field, the span will just expand infinitely. [image]

Is there a way, to have the span act like the input field would and scroll the text to the left as more and more characters are added?

Current span styling:

```
style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 0.25px; left: 2px; padding: 1px; z-index: 2; pointer-events: none;"
```

**EDIT**

```
<div style="position: relative;" class="input-box">
                    <input style="color: transparent; caret-color: black; z-index: 1;" type="text" name="street[]" id="street_1" class="street
                     input-text"/>

                    <span id="street1span" class="input-text" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0.25px; left: 2px; padding: 1px; z-index: 2; pointer-events: none;" ></span>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This :

```css
span {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="text"] {
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
Span :<span contenteditable="true"></span>
<br><br>
Input:<input type="text" name="">
```

**After Edit your Post :**

```css
span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 2px;
    padding: 1px;
    z-index: 2; 
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;" class="input-box">
    <input style="color: #000; caret-color: black; z-index: 1;" type="text" name="street[]" id="street_1" class="streetinput-text"/>

<span id="street1span" contenteditable="true" class="input-text" >
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: In his case, without content editable but for demo purposes this is the perfect solution.

Comment: This is perfect, but on my site it does not scroll back nicely, like in the snippet here, the text just disappears at the end of the input field

Comment: Could that be because my span is not `contenteditable="true"`?

Comment: Nope, did not fix it... hmm

Comment: Did you change anything or just proved that it should be working?

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš, Yes,i change your code! see it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot see what have you changed apart from `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Unfortunately that is necessary for my site... I guess i'm out of luck

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš I helped you as much as possible.

Comment: Yes, I know, I can see that the code should be working ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```css
* {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
 input {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.25px; 
    left: 2px;
    padding: 1px;
    overflow-x:auto
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" placeholder="something span"  />
</div>
```

Comment: This is still just an input field

Answer (score 0):

you can add `overflow-x:auto;` in your span

Answer (score 0):

You can do

html

```
<span id="flow"></span>
```

CSS

```
.flow{
     overflow : hidden/auto; // depending on your choice
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<div style="position: relative;" class="input-box">
    <input style="color: transparent; caret-color: black; z-index: 1;" type="text" name="street[]" id="street_1" class="street
        input-text"/>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <hr />
    <span id="street1span" class="input-text" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding: 1px; border:1px solid #ccc; width:300px; overflow-x:scroll;" > hellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhellhello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Any explanation to what you're suggesting?

Comment: A good answer should include text saying what you did and why you did it, what did the user do wrong?